# MySQL to get previous year record

Tags: mysql, sql

I want a MySQL query to fetch previous year records. 
I already wrote a query to fetch current year records but I want previous year record also. There is a column called "date_created" based upon this date I have to fetch the status of the meterial.

```
SELECT material_status, COUNT(*) c
FROM purchase_order
WHERE YEAR(date_created) = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND material_status='open';
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

to get last year data

```
SELECT material_status, COUNT(*) c
FROM purchase_order
WHERE YEAR(date_created) = YEAR(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)) AND material_status='open';
```

Comment: you can also do `YEAR(date_created) = YEAR(CURDATE()) - 1`

Answer (score -2):

Query to see how the date time functions for MySQL works

Try This:

```
select 
CURRENT_USER() user, 
CURRENT_TIME() current_time, 
CURRENT_DATE() current_date, 
year(CURRENT_DATE()) current_year, 
YEAR(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)) previous_year;
```